# Divs go under other divs despite z index set

Tags: html, css

Live link here

### #

When you hover number of products in cart, the list of them goes under nav bar.
And when you hover menu item- dropdown menu goes under slider

i gave `#cartinfo` `z-index` of `10000` and made it `!important`. 
did same thing for `ul.submenu`
Also, gave `#sliderz` (slider container) `z-index` of `-1`

It didn't help.

Comment: Don't post a link to your site; it's discouraged. Instead, post your HTML and CSS here using the code features and, if possible, include a link to a JSFiddle or CodePen representation of your site.

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm using a 3rd party theme, and didn't want to miss a piece of code that could be the problem. I understand why, though. And will do so in a future.

Comment: It's okay if you don't get it right the first time; if you post what you think is the relevant code, and it turns out to be the wrong section, someone will invariably notice and they will usually point it out, often suggesting where to look at the same time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [**What No One Told You About Z-Index**](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

The problem are stacking contexts: since the submenu belongs to `.navigation`, which has `z-index: 1`, then `.mainsilder`, which also has `z-index: 1`, overlaps ALL navigation contents, even those which have `z-index: 10000`.

To fix it, you can use

```
.navigation {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Note this will place ALL navigation contents above `.mainsilder` (and others), not only the submenu.

Comment: You beat me to it! Great Article!

Comment: It fiexed the nav. Tnx! I tried giving div containing cart a z-index of 3 assuming it would work it would work the same way, but it keeps going under the nav.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall having run by a similar problem. After a lot of debugging I found a typo. There was a missing closing tag `</div>` that was causing the issue.

Comment: remember z-index is relative, so a higher z-index would only apply if the two elements are on the same 'level'.